# bv-enable-int2bv-propagation option

Tags: z3

`(set-option :bv-enable-int2bv-propagation true)` works online. But, my local version complaints about it, saying:

> (error "line 1 column 43: unknown parameter
>   'bv_enable_int2bv_propagation', this is an old parameter name, invoke
>   'z3 -p' to obtain the new parameter list")

What's the new parameter name? I tried to find it in the output of `z3 -p`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the `unstable` (working-in-progress) branch, or one of the nightly builds. The nightly builds are produced using the `unstable` branch.
This branch contains modifications that will be available in the next release (Z3 v4.3.2). [Rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com) is running the official release (i.e., `master` branch). The next release (v4.3.2) will contain a new parameter setting infrastructure. The options are organized in different modules. 
Moreover, I only ported the most commonly used parameters to the new framework. 
I thought nobody was using the parameter `:bv-enable-int2bv-propagation` :)

Anyway, 
[I fixed this issue](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/1c96a7d52f48b42891e5f40fa47e0b38c77a0b2e). I added the parameter `smt.bv.enable-int2bv` in the `unstable` branch.
You can get the fix now by recompiling the `unstable` branch, or waiting the fix to be available in the nightly builds. The parameter `smt.bv.enable-int2bv` will also be in the next official release v4.3.2. [Here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) are instruction on how to compile the `unstable` branch.

Comment: Thank you, Leonardo. I got the precompiled Mac binary, which is unstable. I'll check out the new version!