# Z3 : Questions About Z3 int2bv?

Tags: z3, smt

I'm a little confused with the Z3 (smt2 format ) operation **int2bv** . I wrote a such smt2 expression :

```
(declare-const t1 Int)
(assert (= ((_ int2bv 2) t1) #b11))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

when I solve it with Z3 ,it got:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun t1 () Int
    0)
)
```

Is that correct?  Shouldn't t1 be 3?  I thought the int2bv operation just transform the int value to the equivalent bitvector value. But it seems not!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int2bv` function is essentially handled as uninterpreted (as stated in the documentation), so the semantics are not precise. There have previously been a few questions about those conversion functions, they might be helpful here too:

[Z3: an exception with int2bv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326466/z3-an-exception-with-int2bv)

[Check overflow with Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821320/check-overflow-with-z3)

[bv-enable-int2bv-propagation option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798984/bv-enable-int2bv-propagation-option)