# Z3 int2bv operation

Tags: z3, smt

I am experiencing some issues with the bitvector operations. In particular, given the following model. I was expecting `var0` to be `11`.

```
(declare-const var1 Int)
(declare-const var0 Int)
(assert (= var1 10))
(assert (= var0 ((_ bv2int 32) (bvor ((_ int2bv 32) var1) ((_ int2bv 32) 1)))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

However, the solution given by Z3 for fun was:

```
sat (model 
(define-fun var1 () Int 10) 
(define-fun var0 () Int (- 1)) 
)
```

This means, -1 instead of 10. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `int2bv` and `bv2int` are uninterpreted functions. The semantics might not work as you expected.

See [Z3 : Questions About Z3 int2bv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914582/z3-questions-about-z3-int2bv)