# Incorrect result of sum int-casted BitVec using Z3, Z3py

Tags: sum, z3, z3py, bitvector

I am using the following python code to find two binary numbers that:

- sum to a certain number
- their highest bits cast to integers must sum up to 2

The second constraint is more important to me; and in my case, it will scale: let's say it might become that highest bits of [N] number must sum up to [M].

I am not sure why z3 does not give the correct result. Any hints? Thanks a lot.

```
def BV2Int(var):
    return ArithRef(Z3_mk_bv2int(ctx.ref(), var.as_ast(), 0), var.ctx)

def main():
    s = Solver()
    s.set(':models', True) 
    s.set(':auto-cfgig', False) 
    s.set(':smt.bv.enable_int2bv',True) 

    x = BitVec('x',4)
    y = BitVec('y',4)
    s = Solver()
    s.add(x+y == 16, Extract(3,3,x) + Extract(3,3,y) == 2)
    s.check()
    print s.model()
    # result: [y = 0, x = 0], fail both constraint

    s = Solver()
    s.add(x+y == 16, BV2Int(Extract(3,3,x)) + BV2Int(Extract(3,3,y)) == 2)
    s.check()
    print s.model()
    # result: [y = 15, x = 1], fail the second constraint
```

**Update:** Thanks the answer from Christoph. Here is a quick fix:

- Extract(3,3,x) -> ZeroExt(SZ, Extract(3,3,x)) where SZ is the bit width of RHS minus 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Aside: auto-cfgig should be auto-config.)

Note that bv2int and int2bv are essentially treated as uninterpreted, so if this part is crucial to your problem, then don't use them (see [documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/group__capi.html#gac87b227dc3821d57258d7f53a28323d4) and [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914582/z3-questions-about-z3-int2bv)).

The problem with this example are the widths of the bit-vectors. Both `x` and `y` are 4-bit variables, and the numeral `16` as a 4-bit vector is `0` (modulo 2^4), so, indeed `x + y` is equal to `16` when `x=0` and `y=0`.

Further, the `Extract(...)` terms extract 1-bit vectors, which means that the sum `Ex.. + Ex..` is again a 1-bit value and the numeral `2` as a 1-bit vector is `0` (modulo 2^1), i.e., it is indeed the case that `Ex... + Ex... = 2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Christoph. so is the second case similar? That is we got 1 bit extracted. After wrapped up with BV2Int, we then got a 1 bit integer, so we still need to chop the RHS to become a 1 bit integer.